# Android holo disables spinner

Tags: android, themes, spinner

I came across a problem while using android holo theme. As a short history behind the problem, I had to change the color of some radio buttons and decided to try using holo. Everything worked really well except that my spinner is not selecting items. It opens the drop down menu, it populates the menu but when I tap on it nothing happened. I change back to the default theme and it worked again. Same code same XML just different theme. Has anybody dealt with this problem ?

Thank you and sorry if this question was raised before but I couldn't find anything about this.

Here is the xml for styles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="RadioButtonAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
  <item name="android:button">@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Update

I managed to find my way around the problem by downloading the spinner from holo as well. I still would like to understand why my original problem but for now this works.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting proper theme for your spinner? For instance: `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner` ?

Comment: I'm just setting up the theme for radio buttons. I didn't download anything for spinner. Do I have to set the spinner through Holo too?

Comment: Could you post some xml with styles?

Comment: i posted the xml for styles that holo generated, that is the one i use. I noticed that holo generates 2 sets of value folders values and values-v11. Does anybody know for what you use the second folder ?